# CustomReflectionContext how to return dynamic attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.5

I want to hide the original `Object.GetType()` with one of my own

For example instead of:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class @Class
{
}
```

I want to generate the attribute on the fly like:

```
public class @Class
{
     public new Type GetType(){
           return new MyCustomTypeContext().Map(base.GetTypeinfo())
     }
}
```

Where `MyCustomTypeContext` would wrap the original type from `GetType()` around so that when you call `myClassInstance.GetType().Attributes`, I can supply the caller an instance of `MyCustomAttribute` at runtime (and not statically bound like in the former case).

I have been poring the default implementation and found nothing, I could create a proxy over the original type implementation - but that's way too much work. Hoping someone will be able to solve this elegantly.

Comment: Mind you, by _hiding_ the lower level method, you don't prevent it from being used. Only if the calling code already _knows_ it's working against a `@Class` will it call your new method. If it only knows it as the base `object` type (or other inherited/interfaced type) it will still call the _original_ `Object.GetType` method.

Comment: Yeah I'll declare the interface to this type even with generic, so all calls to GetType will be at this level or higher (ie children)

Comment: Would simply implementing an interface with a helper method be sufficient? Something like `static object[] GetAttributes(object obj) { if (obj is IHaveRuntimeAttributes) { return ((IHaveRuntimeAttributes)obj).GetRuntimeAttributes() } else { return obj.GetType().Attributes; } }`?

Comment: If you're guaranteed that all consumers will treat this as `@Class` and simply won't upcast it to `object`, then it will work fine. Might cause a few headaches and WTFs, but it'll work. I'm guessing this is part of a custom API and consumers won't be put off by this? Definitely not standard practice.

Comment: No, probably not. The thing is I want to "trick" my serializer into thinking there's some attributes there, when in fact there isn't. I don't want to decorate every property with something like [DataContract] all over the place. Just to follow convention over configuration. And for me, I get tired decorating the same stuff over and over again.

Comment: If you're guaranteed that all consumers will treat this as @Class and simply won't upcast it to object, then it will work fine. Might cause a few headaches and WTFs <-- hahaha that's part of the fun of this job!  :P

Comment: So this question is less about being able to hide the method, but the best way to sort of... wrap the actual type to supply custom attributes? You mentioned this is "my" serializer: is this a custom serializer implementation or are you leveraging a built-in one? If the latter, not sure if you can do this; I've certainly never come across doing anything like that. Then again, I learn something new just about everyday on StackOverflow.

Comment: Leveraging a built-in one. Hoping I can trick it into seeing things... Hate littering my classes with a bunch of attributes, repeatedly. I want it to be POCO as much as possible.

Comment: Not sure if there's an elegant solution then. In my experience, I _completely_ separate my business objects from my data transfer objects/layer. So I just decorate the DTOs however I need to for whatever serializer I need to use. Yeah, it's a bit of house-keeping, but it's not that bad especially if they're separated from my business layer; then the `[DataContract]` tags tend to actually _mean_ something. Perhaps there's some method of doing what you're looking for, but I don't know it.